# Browers hangs for super user question

Tags: discussion, bug, status-declined

Just now , one user posted question : https://superuser.com/questions/68649/help-me-with-my-cisco-ios-config.

When ever i am clicking that question Browser hangs for some time and recovered and show message for unresponsive script error message

The message is this and asking for stop script or continue

> A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, open the script in the debugger, or let the script continue.
>
> Script: http://sstatic.net/su/js/master.js?v=5005:1

Answer (score 2):

Not really a bug; a user inappropriately syntax highlighted an enormous block of non-code.

(also worked fine in Chrome, which has an outstanding JavaScript engine -- join the power!)

I just un-indented it and used `<pre></pre>` instead.

update: we don't do syntax highlighting on Super User any more, so this issue is moot.

Comment: Thanks Jeff . I just want to know if the user inappropriately syntax highlighted also we need to exception handling and provide proper handling . then only it will be good , other wise if we didn't handle those error  browser will handle that . that is issue ( thats my thought )

Comment: In Linux , I  cant take for Chrome ;)